# PHP Redirect incremental loop

Tags: php

I am trying to figure out a way of redirecting to different url's in a loop.

For example...I have this url:

```
http://mydomain.com/subfolder/1
```

I need the 1 at the end of the url above to increment by 1 everytime in the loop

So it would do this:

```
redirect here - http://mydomain.com/subfolder/1
redirect here - http://mydomain.com/subfolder/2
redirect here - http://mydomain.com/subfolder/3
```

So it would go:

```
while (a < 100) {
header("Location: http://mydomain.com/subfolder/" Increment number here );
}
```

How can I do this in PHP?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: can you please post code

Comment: you can not redirect someone on multiple ways. One man can run on single way at a time.

Comment: Nothing bad don't worry...just need to check multiple urls for stuff in my own website but this is the first part I need to do.

Comment: In what loop do you mean?

Comment: Still does not make any sense. Does anything like `curl_multi_exec()` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php help?

Comment: You can cache your `$a` value and send a header with `$a + 1` on each execution, using memcache.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

if $a is your incremented no then

```
$a=1;
 while ($a < 100) {
  header("Location: http://mydomain.com/subfolder/'".$a."'");
   $a++;
  }
```

Comment: I've not change the loop. used OP's loop. just used $ before 'a'

Comment: This makes no sense at all! A redirect usaully terminates the execution of the script, so you just redirect once.

Answer (score 0):

You could retrieve the page each time you get to your script like so :

```
$lastpage = basename($_SERVER[REQUEST_URI])
```

Then increment it and redirect to the next page when needed.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

If you have a rewrite rule that rewrites `/subfolder/(\d+)` to `script.php?index=$1`, then you can try:

`header("Location: /subfolder/" . ($_GET["index"] + 1));`

;-)

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
<?php
    $myvar = Array();
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; ++$i) {
        echo $myvar[$i] = 'header("Location: http://mydomain.com/subfolder/'.$i.'")';
    }
?>
```